# HTML - how to get the answers on a quiz<form>

Tags: html, coldfusion

```
<form action="quiz.cfm" method="get">
<fieldset>
<legend>Your Details</legend>

<div>
<label for="What is the length of a banana?">What is the length of a banana?:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="What is the length of a banana?" value="" maxlength="100" /><br>
</div>

<div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Hello.
That is the code I have so far.
I want to know what I am supposed to do to actually get the answers, send them to my e-mail for example.

Thank you in advance,
Iluvpresident

Comment: Might depend on just what `quiz.fm` is/does.

Comment: This is my first interaction with .cfm. 
<div style="background:#eee;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:32px;"><p>Thank you for participating!</p></div> That's what in my .cfm file

Comment: You will want to look at the cfmail tag.

Comment: You want to POST and not GET. You don't want spaces and special characters in an input name.

Comment: Based on everything I've read, learning the basics would be a good investment of time and effort.  I believe easycfm.com has tutorials.  You may also want to google "ben forta books" and see what the most recent edition of the Web Application Construction Kit is.  Even the old ones are pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

The code below should be incorporated into the "quiz.cfm" page.

```
<cfmail 
    from="fromemailaddress" 
    to="toEmailAddress" 
    subject="A new form entry has been submitted"> 

A customer inquiry was posted to our website: 

Text : #Form.answer# 

</cfmail>
```

Comment: The above code assumes the text box has a name of answer i.e <input type="text" name="answer" value="" maxlength="100" /><br>

Comment: What does "fromemailaddress" exactly mean? Can this be my own e-mail address?

Comment: It is a placeholder for the from address you would like to use.